# Chart.js bar chart: show tooltip on label hover

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js library to draw a bar chart and I want to show tooltip not only on bar hover, but also on x-axis label hover for that bar. I found `onHover` method for configuration, but it only lets me access the array of currently hovered bars, which isn't useful.

So, how can I access mouse event and maybe take position from there to compare it against bar labels positions? Or there is another way to do it?

My current configuration:

```
const countryChartOptions = {
    hover: {
         onHover: this.onChartHover,
    },
};

const onHover = (activeElements) => {
    console.log(activeElements);
};
```

It only prints out hovered bars data, but I'm stuck to figure out how to extend it for behavior I need.

Answer (score 5):

**What about :**

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    // Add this..
    intersect: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It works for me

```
  options: {
      tooltips:{
      intersect : false,
      mode:'index'
      }
   }
```

Comment: The option "index: 'mode' " made all the difference. Without it, the the tooltip wasn't aligned with the cursor. For example, the cursor was over '9' and the tooltip showed the value for the label '5' (or something like that). IMHO this is the correct answer.